# change the dimension of string in C#

Tags: c#

I get data from the web and I put it in a string

```
var URL = "my url";
string ss = (new WebClient()).DownloadString(url);
```

but now the problem is 
I want to convert this string to an array of char
I tried many functions but I couldn't cause I don't know the size
can you please tell me how can I convert in C#?
thanks

Comment: Can you provide the code you've already tried?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ezftk57x(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `char[] array = ss.ToCharArray();`

Comment: What does "converting a string to an array of characters" have to do with either downloading the string or "change the dimension of string"?

Comment: @JonSkeet Not much apparently.

Comment: I tried this also but i didn't get the reslut

Comment: i tried 
ss.toCharArray();
ss.split(',');

Comment: and also 
char[] a = ss.tostring();

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to cast the string :

```
string url = "some text";
char[] array = url.ToArray();
```

EDIT : following @fubo comment there is a built in method to convert the string :

```
char[] array = url.ToCharArray();
```

Comment: thanks ... but i tried this befoe but i couldn't get the result

Comment: Ok so your problem should be related to the string you retrieve from the server

Answer (score 0):

```
var charArray = ss.ToCharArray();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I'm sorry cause i didn't give any explanation ... all i do is to get data from any web page then i will implement the data in 2 algorithms to improve a new algorithm